# how can I enable pop ups in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am very beginner at Java and Selenium so my apologies in advance if my question is primary.

I am writing a test, when I click on a button another window is supposed to be opened but I get pops-up block notice, how can I enable pop ups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Enable and Disable Pop-ups

#### Chrome

To disable the popup blocker in Chrome, create a **chromeOptions** capability, and pass the --**disable-popupblocking** argument to the capability.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

#### IE

To enable the popups in IE, use the **browserstack.ie.enablePopups** capability.

```
caps.setCapability("browserstack.ie.enablePopups", "true");
```

#### Safari

To enable the popups in Safari, use the **browserstack.safari.enablePopups** capability.

```
caps.setCapability("browserstack.safari.enablePopups", "true");
```

Comment: Hmm this might be helpful then.. [Enable Disable Popups](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java#enable-disable-popups)

Answer (score 0):

IE answer will be valid only against browserstack!

What I found working for now for IE is the below code:

```
var regKey = default(RegistryKey);
regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\New Windows", true);
regKey.SetValue("PopupMgr", 0);
regKey.Close();
```