# How to programmatically open Safari->preferences in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, safari, appium

I want to open programmatically **Safari** -> **Preferences** > **Security tab** > Uncheck **Block pop-up windows** using Selenium Java. Does anyone here already have this?

Comment: That is most likely outside the scope of selenium.

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518009/how-can-i-enable-pop-ups-in-selenium